# Differentiation between 'Entity' and 'Table'

Tags: database

Can someone tell me the easy way to explain the differentiation between an entity and a table in database?

Comment: Do you have context?

Comment: Hmm.. In general database context? table-record-attribute-method-entity @RowlandShaw

Answer (score 17):

Entity is a logical concept of relational database model. And table is used to express it, but there is a slight difference. Table expresses not only entities, but also relations.

For example, assume that you want to make a database of projects and employees of a company. Entity is a unit of information that has meanings by itself. In this case, there will be two entities - "Project" and "Employee". Each entity has its own attributes.

In relational DB model, there is another idea, 'relation'. If employees participate in several projects, then we can say that there is a relation with a name 'works_on'.

Sometimes, relation can have its own attribute. In this case, 'works_on' relation can have attribute 'start_date' and so on. And if this relation is M:N relation(Like this case: In project 1, there are 5 employees. Employee A works on two projects.), then you have to make an extra table to express this relation. (If you don't make an extra table when the relation is M:N, then you have to insert too many duplicated rows into both 'Project' and 'Employee' table.)

```
CREATE TABLE works_on(
  employee,
  project_id,
  start_date
)
```

Answer (score 5):

An entity resides in a table, it is a single set of information, i.e: if you have a database of employees, then an employee is an entity. A table is a group of fields with certain parameters.

Basically everything is stored in a table, entities goes into tables.

Answer (score 1):

In a relational database the concept is the same. An entity is a table.

In OOP (Oriented Object Programming) there is a nice article in [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97337_01/ias102_otn/buslog.102/bc4j/bc_awhatisaneo.htm):

> In general terms, entity objects encapsulate the business policy and
>   data for
>
> the logical structure of the business, such as product lines,
>   departments, sales, and regions
>
> business documents, such as invoices, change orders, and service
>   requests
>
> physical items, such as warehouses, employees, and equipment
>
> Another way of looking at it is that an entity object stores the
>   business logic and column information for a database table (or view,
>   synonym, or snapshot). An entity object caches data from a database
>   and provides an object-oriented representation of it.
>
> Depending on how you want to work, you can create entity objects from
>   existing database tables (reverse generation) or define entity objects
>   and use them to create database tables (forward generation).

Answer (score 0):

There is little difference between an entity and a table, but first we should define the concepts of “tuple” and “attribute”. I want to express those concepts with a table.

[image]

Here is an example of a table. As you can see it has some columns. Each column represents an attribute and each line represents a tuple(row). This is the employee table. In this example, the table is being used for representing an entity which is employee. However, if we create a new table named superior to specify the superiority relationship between those employees, it would be a table that represents a relation. In summary, we can use tables for representing both the entities and relations so entities and tables are not the same.